# How to find next character in Golang?

Tags: go

I'm just doing some algorithms problems out of interest in golang. I understand that in other languages to find the next character alphabetically I can bitshift the character, as a character (I'm thinking of C) is really a number.

So I tried doing

```
"a" >> 2
```

Or something to that effect, but there is a type mismatch.

I'd like to know how I can achieve this.

Comment: The right syntax is `'a' >> 2` and it does work, but how does this tell you the next character?

Comment: funny, I ran that in the playground and it didn't work. In any case, I'm really really rusty with this - I thought I'd shift, then cast back to a character.

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd expect `'a' >> 2` to give you the next character alphabetically in any language(?). It certainly won't do that in C.

Comment: Vote of -1 is enough

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure where you get the idea that this gives you the 'next character'. This is not true in any language. What `'a' >> 2` does is this:

- 'a' is interpreted as `int32(97)` ([example](http://play.golang.org/p/tkYcX7gO1x))
- `>>` means 'shift X right by Y bits'. Shifting something right by 2 bits is functionally the same as an integer divide by 4. So `(x >> 2) == (x / 4)`. ([example](http://play.golang.org/p/0F3vr7srbf))
- `97 / 4 == 24`. The `b` character has ASCII value `98`. So this doesn't get you anywhere near. ([example](http://play.golang.org/p/fiMbbbgnWG))

#### More on the bit shifting

Bit shifting is most obvious when considering a number in its binary notation. For the expression `z = x >> y`, we can note the following:

```
x(97):  01100001
y(2):   00000010
        -------- >>
z(24):  00011000
```

Note that all the bits in `x` have simply been moved to the right by two bits. The `1` that fell off the end is dropped.

Similarly, you can 'shift left' (`<<`). Just like `x >> 1` is the same as `x / 2`, `x << 1` is the same as `x * 2`.

Expression: `5>>1 == 5/2 == 2`:

```
x(5):   00000101
y(1):   00000001
        -------- >>
z(2):   00000010
```

Expression: `5<<1 == 5*2 == 10`:

```
x(5):   00000101
y(1):   00000001
        -------- <<
z(10):  00001010
```

#### Actually getting the next character

If you want the character directly following `'a'`, you simply add 1 to it as evidenced in this [example](http://play.golang.org/p/rFQX-fHJE2).

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to shift a string, not a byte, like @Not_a_Golfer said `'a'>>2` should work fine.

However to get the next character you can do something like:

```
func nextChar(ch byte) byte {
    if ch += 1; ch > 'z' {
        return 'a'
    }
    return ch
}
func main() {
    fmt.Println(string(nextChar('a')))
}
```

Of course it'd be more complex if you need more than a-z support, take a look at the [`unicode`](http://golang.org/pkg/unicode/) package and [this](https://blog.golang.org/strings) blog post about go strings.